# R: Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) , Argument 111 when combining data frames

Tags: r

I am using R version 3.4.3. 
I have two data.frames of different size with some common column and some different ones. I want to combine both while keeping the different columns between both (i.e. adding NAs in the dataframe where such column was not present). I an using "dplyr" package function bind_rows:

```
    mydata_combine <- bind_rows(mydata,mydata2)
```

and I get the following error:

```
   Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 111 must be length 1309, not 2618
```

where the common columns have the same name and data type and:

```
    > is.data.frame(mydata)
    [1] TRUE
    > is.data.frame(mydata2)
    [1] TRUE
    > ncol(mydata)
    [1] 127
    > ncol(mydata2)
    [1] 112
    > nrow(mydata)
    [1] 1309
    > nrow(mydata2)
    [1] 364
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error? I have used this function multiple times before with similar data and never had such problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do:

`df_combine <- merge(mydata, mydata2)`

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried that, but it creates a 0-row dataframe with all the columns in the first data frame. So it creates a data frame of 0 obs. and 127 variables.

Comment: Then u can use the rbind.fill from the package plyr